# Изменение порядка стилей с css-файле

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, npm

При вёрстке сайтов пишу стили в определённом для себя удобном порядке: сначала padding, margin, потом всё, связанное с позиционированием и т.д. Но понял, что не всегда получается писать в таком порядке и переносить бывает очень лень. Поэтому хочется узнать: может есть какой-нибудь плагин, который сам переносит стили в похожем порядке, или может это можно самому с помощью js как-либо сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А кто-то указывает стили в алфавитном порядке. Так или иначе они сработают, если речь о css-правилах для одного селектора. Не стоит уделять столько внимания группировке правил, я думаю.

Comment: не нужно так делать, от слова никогда. порядок стилей определяет специфичность их применения

Comment: @Serj1c, вы сейчас с кем разговаривали? ))

Comment: @Quazimorda, с автором офк)

Comment: https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/